# Can you have CPU VT-x enabled on a VPS?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vps, intel-vt-x

I'm using a VPS server on Ubuntu 17.04, from [these guys](https://contabo.com)

I'd like to install some components but it requires CPU Virtualisation to be enabled.

#### Question 1: Is it possible to have CPU VT-x enable for a VPS?

#### Question 2: If yes, is it common for VPS hosting providers to offer this? (I want to make sure i'm not asking something stupid)

Some hardware details:

- CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2620 v3
- Virtualization software (which they use i guess): QEMU

What i've tried so far:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

Comment: You're trying to run a VM inside of your VM? If you're trying to run multiple applications in isolation, why not run them in containers?

Comment: Hey Cristian, did you got an answer to your question? I'm looking for the same thing from the same guys :)

Comment: @ZedTuX Yep, got an answer from them that its not supported :(

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! Did you find any other that allows it?

Comment: @ZedTuX No, since having more thought about it, performance would be impacted by this anyway, so pretty much it defeated the initial purpose. (I was trying to setup a kubernetes cluster).

Comment: Thank you @CristianE. for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question 1: Is it possible to have CPU VT-x enable for a VPS?

Yes, it is possible to have VT-x enabled in a VM, this is called [Nested Virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization#Nested_virtualization).

> Question 2: If yes, is it common for VPS hosting providers to offer this? (I want to make sure i'm not asking something stupid)

I can't really tell you what typical VPS providers support or whether your VPS provider supports it. But I don't think that's a stupid question, so I'd just go ahead and ask them.

Looking at cloud providers, [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances) and [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/) support it, while it seems AWS doesn't support it yet, maybe that is a data point that might be helpful to you?